# Session is not getting maintained between https and http

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

In my *JSP/servlet* application some pages are in https and others in only http.
The login page is in https, and I've noticed that when I login and redirect to an http page,then the session is not being maintained.Anyone could help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Check this Question [HTTPS to HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635425/tomcat-keep-session-when-moving-from-https-to-http)

Answer (score 1):

You should not move from HTTPS to HTTP as you will loose [confidentiality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)

If you still wish to do this, you can manually pass on the Session ID from login(HTTPS) to the redirected page(HTTP).

The SSL Session ID (attribute name - `javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id`) should not be revealed and hence it won't get carried over to HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the redirect url that you direct to, doesnt not have [jsessionid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID).

try this

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath + "/myServlet"));
```

but please be aware since you are exposing the sessionid in the url , your exposing your webapp for a 
[Session Fixation Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)